# Equivalent win API in *nix

Tags: linux, api, winapi, memory-management, freebsd

I am looking for the equivalent methods (in FreeBSD & Linux) of the following WinAPI:

- CreateFile(); or OpenFile();
- CreateFileMapping();
- MapViewOfFile();

Comment: I don't think that every WinAPI system call has a Linux equivalent (or vice versa) - even if for those you ask they are some. I mean that it is better to understand the genuine Posix (or Unix) philosophy that to mimick what you know very well in WinAPI...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about these ?

- [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) / `creat(2)`
- [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html)
- [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

Not completely equivalent but should get you started.

Comment: Note that `mmap()` combines the functions of `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()`.